# Can you set up a table format on Pages documents from the beginning?

Tags: pages

I want to set up a Pages document with a specific format, a certain table with a certain number of cells on each page, of a certain size. Instead of just copying and pasting this table into multiple pages, is there a way I can set up the document in the settings so that it knows to automatically put such a table in every page?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Pages document with the desired table (and any styles you want).

Then save as a template.

New documents created with the template should meet your needs.